# Unity - how to get collision angle on trigger enter?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, angle

I'm trying to build a brick-breaker game, and I want to aim the ball according to where the ball hit the paddle.
For example if the ball hit paddle's right edge, it should go to the right (and up).
Assuming the paddle has a box (or capsule) collider and the ball has a sphere collider, how can I do this?
Thanks for any help!

And I want to get the pad's velocity as well. The code below returns 0, any ideas why?

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other:Collider)
{
    if(other.rigidbody){
    V_pad=other.rigidbody.velocity;
    //Here it returns (0,0,0) , also tried other.attachedRigidbody
    }    

    if(other.name=="Pad"){
    rigidbody.velocity = 
Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x, Mathf.Abs(rigidbody.velocity.y + V_pad),0); 
//this part executes but with V_pad.y=0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When two colliders touch in Unity, the [`OnCollisionEnter`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html?from=Collision) method will be called in any components you've added to the same GameObject.  If you define that method with a [`Collision`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collision.html) parameter, you'll get information that includes the point of contact between the two colliders.  You can use this information to work out where on the bat your ball has touched.

Note that, from the ball's point of view, this will always be a point at the "bottom" of the sphere.  You may also want to take into account the angle of the ball's velocity.

**EDIT:** an alternative method (given your coment) might be to use [`Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds.html).  If you use something like `bat.ClosestPointOnBounds(ball)`, you will get the `Vector3` of the point on the bat that is closest to the ball - which for a spherical ball will be the point of collision.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm handling the collision in OnTriggerEnter(c:collider) and I cannot get the c.contacts[0], is there any way I can convert collider to collision?

Comment: col.ClosestPointOnBounds(transform.position) did the trick for me, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Vector3D class to find the direction of the ball, then dependent on what surface it should hit change that component of the vector. Use the Unity [Vector3D API](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) for more help. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a sphere collider for the paddle as well. You can move the center of the collider a little bit behind the paddle and scale the collider to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unCheck the  Is Trigger setting in the collider and use OnCollision instead of OnTrigger. In the OnCollision you can use something like this to calculate the output direction.

var direction = Vector3.Reflect(lastFrameVelocity.normalized, collision.contacts[0].normal);